# How to change the date format in SQL select script

Tags: sql, sap-ase, sybase-ase15

In my Sybase DB I have a table called employee_leaves. So the select query statement is as shown below:

```
SELECT EmployeeCode,EmployeeName,ApplicationDate  FROM dbo.employee_leaves
```

Where I have challenge is that the **ApplicationDate** comes in this format:    16/04/2023 7:09:47.563

From the Select Query statement, I want each of the **ApplicationDate** to be formatted and displayed as:

```
2023-04-16 07:09:47.563
```

yyyy-MM-dd ....

I tried this but not working:

```
SELECT EmployeeCode,EmployeeName,format(ApplicationDate,'yyyy-MM-dd,hh:mm:ss') FROM dbo.employee_leaves
```

How do I achieve this from the select * FROM dbo.employee_leaves

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version are you using?

Comment: @markp-fuso - Sybase ASE

Comment: Did you try `select EmployeeCode,EmployeeName, convert(datetime, ApplicationDate,23) as ApplicationDate FROM dbo.employee_leaves` ? [Docs are here](https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/BABDBAHF.htm)

Comment: @KirsSudh - Yes. But this error:     ---------------  BMS -- Number (208) Severity (16) State (1) Server (MyDB) dbo.employee_leaves not found. Specify owner.objectname or use sp_help to check whether the object exists (sp_help may produce lots of output

Comment: `Msg 208` (object not found) means you have an invalid table reference (`dbo.employee_leaves`) in your query; this could be a case of running the query in the wrong database, or trying to access a table that's owned by some other user (ie, table is not owned by `dbo`)

Comment: what is the datatype of the `ApplicationDate` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `ApplicationDate` column is defined with a datatype of `datetime` ...

In `Sybase ASE` you want to look at the [`convert()` function](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_ASE/2df920cd5b1644e5a065d55b637d5e92/aacb76eabc2b1014a15ce085fd168d48.html) with a focus on the 3rd argument (aka the `style` setting).

For OP's desired format this should work:

```
-- style=140 requires ASE 16+
-- style=140 returns 6 digits after decimal => varchar(23) should drop the last 3 digits

SELECT EmployeeCode,
       EmployeeName,
       convert(varchar(23),ApplicationDate,140)
FROM dbo.employee_leaves

-- ASE 15.x does not have style=140 so we need to get creative
-- will (obviously) also work for ASE 16

SELECT EmployeeCode,
       EmployeeName,
             convert(varchar(10),ApplicationDate,23)     || " " ||
             convert(varchar(8) ,ApplicationDate,20)     || "." ||
       right(convert(varchar(12),ApplicationDate,20),3) 
FROM dbo.employee_leaves
```

**NOTES:**

- above queries tested/verified on an `ASE 16.0 SP04 GA` instance
- if the desired format is not available in the `style` chart you can typically build your own format with a combination of other `convert(type,column,style)`, `substring()`, `left()`, `right()` and `str_replace()` calls
- if the `ApplicationDate` column is defined as `varchar(N)` (or `char(N)`) then you'll likely need to look at appending a series of `substring()` calls and literal strings to get the desired output format

Answer (score 0):

[This documentation](https://www.sqlines.com/sybase-asa-to-sql-server/dateformat) can be referred for different outputs in case you need in future. Dont bother about the conversion mentioned in the document. We need only formatting.

The desired output may be achieved from the following code

```
SELECT EmployeeCode,EmployeeName,DATEFORMAT(ApplicationDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS.SSSSSS') AS ApplicationDate FROM employee_leaves
```

Allow us to advice you further in case this dint work as expected. The result has been obtained locally.